# Configure a complete costume protocol as IE Trusted Sites

Tags: internet-explorer

I created a costume protocol (for a namespace extension application),
structered: protocol:\path\to\file.

I'm trying to add the pathes in this protocol to Internet Option's Trusted Sites
(to disable a widows warning popping every time i use the protocol),
but windows doesn't let me add "protocol:\*\" as a trusted site.

Any ideas?
tell me if more details in needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to enable this, If you set this setting via GPO you aren't limited with the use of wildcards, and can set "protocol:*\"

Answer (score 0):

When we add sites to the IE Trusted Sites, the site url should be an individual URLs or entire domains, like "http://www.microsoft.com" or "*.microsoft.com".

Try to refer to [this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/815141/ie-enhanced-security-configuration-changes-browsing-experience#61) and [this article](https://nefaria.com/2009/10/adding-trusted-sites-for-ie-via-the-registry/) to add sites to the IE Trusted sites.

Comment: Hi,i'm familiar with this.